# Integrating Twitpic with OAuth Echo authentication into iPhone application

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, twitpic

Has anyone had any luck integrating Twitpic's new OAuth Echo authentication into their iPhone application? This seemed to be a simple task but it's not getting done. I keep getting 400 or 401 errors.

This is also being discussed here:
[OAuth Echo problems](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/230a7a2aa280eda2/3712b3195c41b1b7?pli=1)

p.s. I'm using Ben Gottlieb's Twitter-OAuth library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I updated http://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth with a working example for Twitpic upload powered by OAuth Echo.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine ?

Comment: Recently, i haven't worked with Twitter or Twitpic. Will take a look when i get some time. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: No worries. Accept an answer, which ever helped you. :)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I found the answer. It's in the post below.

Any news on this?
This Post has the same problem:
[Having problems with uploading photos to TwitPic using OAuth in Objective C on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959490/having-problems-with-uploading-photos-to-twitpic-using-oauth-in-objective-c-on-th)

In the mentioned mailing list they say

> Rich, thanks so much.. my issue ended up being that I was signing my 
>   OAuth Echo header as a POST request (because my request is a POST to 
>   twitpic), not GET.

I tried this but still 401 :P

Anbody got this working?
(I have to admit I am a total noob with this stuff. I too got Ben Gottlieb's Twitter-OAuth library and it works fine.)

Comment: I've had no luck with this, so it's on hold for now. I'll look into this in a couple of days, and will post back.