# Having problems with uploading photos to TwitPic using OAuth in Objective C on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, upload, oauth, photo, twitpic

I have been working on an iPhone app that has a feature of uploading photos to TwitPic.  I have it working with basic authentication.

I am trying to get it working with OAuth.  I am getting authentication errors.  I have studied very carefully the TwitPic documentation.

I am authorising the app by displaying a UI Web View and the it returns a PIN value.  I enter the PIN value in the app and request the token.

I am able to upload status updates to Twitter but not photos.

My code is based on some example code from here:

[Example iPhone app using OAuth](http://www.jaanuskase.com/en/2010/01/an_example_iphone_twitter_app.html)

Here is my code:

```
NSString *url = @"http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json";
NSString *oauth_header = [oAuth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"POST" andUrl:url andParams:nil];

NSLog(@"OAuth header : %@\n\n", oauth_header);

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"];
request.requestMethod = @"POST";

[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Auth-Service-Provider" value:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];   

[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization" value:oauth_header];    

NSData *imageRepresentation = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToUpload, 0.8);        
[request setData:imageRepresentation forKey:@"media"];
[request setPostValue:@"Some Message"  forKey:@"message"];  
[request setPostValue:TWITPIC_API_KEY  forKey:@"key"];  

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

[request start];
```

Here is the OAuth Header:

```
OAuth realm="http://api.twitter.com/", oauth_timestamp="1275492425", oauth_nonce="b686f20a18ba6763ac52b689b2ac0c421a9e4013", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_consumer_key="zNbW3Xi3MuS7i9cpz6fw", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="147275699-jmrjpwk3B6mO2FX2BCc9Ci9CRBbBKYW1bOni2MYs", oauth_signature="d17HImz6VgygZgbcp845CD2qNnI%3D"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HA! I found it! 
We should create the *header* with https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json and post to http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json! (And use GET)

```
    NSString *fakeurl = @"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json";
NSString *oauth_header = [oAuth oAuthHeaderForMethod:@"GET" andUrl:fakeurl andParams:nil];

NSLog(@"OAuth header : %@\n\n", oauth_header);

NSString *url = @"http://api.twitpic.com/2/upload.json";
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
request.delegate = self;
[request addRequestHeader:@"User-Agent" value:@"ASIHTTPRequest"];
request.requestMethod = @"GET";

[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Verify-Credentials-Authorization" value:oauth_header];    
[request addRequestHeader:@"X-Auth-Service-Provider" value:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json"];   


NSData *imageRepresentation = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"IMG_0717.jpg"], 0.2);    
if (imageRepresentation) {
    NSLog(@"Pic not nil");
}
[request setData:imageRepresentation forKey:@"media"];
[request setPostValue:@"twitpic, i hate you. die painfully."  forKey:@"message"];  
[request setPostValue:twitPicKey  forKey:@"key"];  

[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];

[request start];
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **GSTwitPicEngine**: https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine

### Using GSTwitPicEngine:

Initialize the engine with class or as needed:

```
self.twitpicEngine = (GSTwitPicEngine *)[GSTwitPicEngine twitpicEngineWithDelegate:self];
```

Find the authorization token and supply to twitpicEngine with:

```
[twitpicEngine setAccessToken:token];
```

Then to upload image and attach a text message along with it (does not post to twitter):

```
[twitpicEngine uploadPicture:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mypic.png"]  withMessage:@"Hello world!"]; // This message is supplied back in success delegate call in request's userInfo.
```

To upload image only:

```
[twitpicEngine uploadPicture:uploadImageView.image];
```

Upon end of request, one of the delegate methods is called with appropriate data and information.

---

GSTwitPicEngineDelegate protocol specifies two delegate methods:

```
- (void)twitpicDidFinishUpload:(NSDictionary *)response {
  NSLog(@"TwitPic finished uploading: %@", response);

  // [response objectForKey:@"parsedResponse"] gives an NSDictionary of the response one of the parsing libraries was available.
  // Otherwise, use [[response objectForKey:@"request"] objectForKey:@"responseString"] to parse yourself.

  if ([[[response objectForKey:@"request"] userInfo] objectForKey:@"message"] > 0 && [[response objectForKey:@"parsedResponse"] count] > 0) {
    // Uncomment to update status upon successful upload, using MGTwitterEngine's instance.
    // [twitterEngine sendUpdate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [[[response objectForKey:@"request"] userInfo] objectForKey:@"message"], [[response objectForKey:@"parsedResponse"] objectForKey:@"url"]]];
  }
}
```

and

```
- (void)twitpicDidFailUpload:(NSDictionary *)error {
  NSLog(@"TwitPic failed to upload: %@", error);

  if ([[error objectForKey:@"request"] responseStatusCode] == 401) {
    // UIAlertViewQuick(@"Authentication failed", [error objectForKey:@"errorDescription"], @"OK");
  }
}
```

---

All set?

Comment: where to find token ? can you provide example i am using your GSTwitPicEngine

Comment: It was around 3 years ago from now that I used ASIHTTPRequest. It certainly had a benefit of ease of use back then. I have moved away from it long ago though.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth method to generate a header must be GET.  Not POST.

Also url must be https://api.twitter.com/1/account/verify_credentials.json

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, this helped me get it working too :) I also updated http://github.com/jaanus/PlainOAuth with working example code.