# Is there a way to update pictures to TwitPic using MGTwitterEngine

Tags: twitter, oauth, twitpic

I updating my project to use twitter oauth instead of basic auth. I was uploading pictures to twitPic using the basic auth, how to do that with oauth?

I am using MGTwitterEngine for doing the oauth.

I found this about using another library: [Having problems with uploading photos to TwitPic using OAuth in Objective C on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959490/having-problems-with-uploading-photos-to-twitpic-using-oauth-in-objective-c-on-th)

but when I try their demo, it is not working, the response is 401.

not sure what oauth header should be?

any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great library for doing this: GSTwitPicEngine https://github.com/Gurpartap/GSTwitPicEngine, and it is easy to use.